# Python Selenium: Mining output of developer console form Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, console

I'm trying to access the messages which the developer console in firefox displays, and use it in my Python Selenium program (which tests wether certain messages appear on the console). I'm able to get the console to open in the browser, but I can't figure out how to access output.Is this possible? Is the developer console attached to the webpage?

Comment: This seems like an unusual use case. Why do you need to access the console data like this?